# Azure mobile service databases

Tags: database, azure, mobile, service, cloud

I am planning to use azure mobile services for one of our products. I was confused about how can I use any of my existing databases (like MySQL, PostgreSQL, or Oracle instead of SQL database offered by Azure) which is available via TCP?

Kindly confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the JavaScript/Node backend or the .NET backend?

If you're using JS, you'll need to create API scripts and import the Node module for your database.  You can't use the default data scripts since they are only hooked to SQL Azure.

If you're using a .NET backend, there's no restriction whatsoever.  You can use any database available on Azure or install your own in a VM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My aim is to connect an android mobile application to an on premise MySQL/PosgreSQL/Oracle database through azure mobile services